# Div not aligning vertically after line break

Tags: html, css

I'm making an app using phonegap, and in this app there is an agenda witch has the following formating:
http://jsfiddle.net/QwVmv/

It looks good, but the only problem I'm having is when the screen width is too small the location does not line up properly. you can reproduce this by narrowing the result screen of jsfiddle.

**Edit 1**
I'm sorry, i forgot to tell how I would like to display it. I would like to have the text after the line break aligned vertical the same as the rest of the text above it.

The code I used: 
HTML:

```
<div class='wrapper' data-id="+contents[i].id+">
    <div class='datefill'></div>
    <div class='date'>
        <span class='day'>22</span>
        <span class='month'>April</span>
        <span class='year'>2013</span>
    </div>
    <div class='agendaheader' id='agenda1'>
        <div class = 'title'>Open House</div>
        <div class = 'time'>00:00 tot 23 April 2013 - 19:00</div>
        <div class='venue'>a location with a long name!</div>
    </div>
    <div style='clear: both;'></div>
    <div class = 'description' id='description1'>A long discription witch is initially hidden.</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.date {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  color: #999;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.day, .month, .year {
  position: absolute;
}

.day { 
  font-size: 30px;
  top: 15px;
}

.month { 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;  
  font-size: 18px;
}

.year { 
  top: 19px;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  rotation: -90deg !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);  
}

.datefill{
    width:65px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
}


.wrapper{
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.description{
     height: 0;
     max-height: 9999px;
     overflow: hidden;
     -webkit-transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
     transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

html{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
}

body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #1C1C1C;
    background-size: 50px;
    background-image: url("../img/bg.png");
    outline: 0;
}

.wrapper{
    padding:5px;
    background-color: #1A1A1A;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#FA840E;
    border-width:2px;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    margin-right:7%;
    margin-left:7%;     
    box-shadow:
        0 0 0 2px hsl(0, 0%, 0%),
        0 0 0 4px hsl(30, 96%, 52%);
}
```

Comment: You can make the div have a `min-width`. It will go off the screen when too small, but if you don't want that then what do you expect? [See Here](http://jsfiddle.net/QwVmv/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve this is to add

```
.agendaheader {
    margin-left: 65px;
}
```

The problem is caused due to the `.datefill` being a floated element, so the other inline elements naturally wrap around it.

**Edit:**  <strike>Alternatively, you could simplify the markup and CSS by using `display:inline-block` instead of `float` which will remove the need for a *clearing* `<div>`.</strike>

Your current markup using `float` is a good approach to have the other elements naturally resize and not jump down to the next line when the width is small which would happen with `inline-block`.

Comment: Why couldn't i think of this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think rhetorical questions are sometimes "dangerous", cause you almost made me guess why you couldn't think of this yourself ;-)